# Clicking two buttons in selenium python after waiting for them

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm waiting for the page to load and when I click one button after using WebDriverWait, it works. When I try to click another button after the first button has been pressed, I get a TimeoutExceptionError raised: 'raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException'

```
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(20000)

# if I just have one, it works. If I have two, it doesn't work and the exception is raised.
moreAttributesButton = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(("xpath", "//*[@id='main-content']/section[3]/div[2]/button"))).click() 
readMoreButton = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(("xpath", "//*[@id='main-content']/section[4]/div[2]/button"))).click()
```